# How to calibrate DIY Brushed ESC powered by 3.7v

Tags: esc, diy, brushed-motors

I build a **DIY Arduino drone**. I also build a working *DIY brushed ESC*. I use 720 DC brushed motor. Let me please inform you that the min Throttle and the Max Throttle not working as expected.

1. Min Throttle **not starts** from configured minThrottle.
2. Max Throttle **not reach** from the configured maxThrottle.

Here's the config of throttle in arduino firmware:

- MinThrottle = 1150
- List MaxThrottle = 2000
- MinCommand = 1000

Besides, I use Flysky fs-i6 *Transmitter* and Flysky 4ch-fs2A *Receiver*.

I watched many tutorial in Youtube but still not working. The drone can take off, but not too high. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do all what Youtube and another tutorial related to this question. Further, finally I know that, ESC can only be calibrated when there is a chip to **STORE** the calibration execution (both min and max throttle).

For some DIY brushed ESC *with no chips on it*, it can not be calibrated since it is directly controlled by core board (eg. arduino).